# NOT NULL constraint failed when save ModelForm

Tags: django, modelform

I am new in Django (1.9)

I have a NOT NULL constraint failed when I save my ModelForm and i don't understand why ...

I propose to the user a form to post a comment and the only field include in the form is "text", i want to set the excluded fields in my view after the validation and before save in database

Models.py :

```
class Commentaire(models.Model):
    text = RichTextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    publish = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "/%s/%s" % (self.pub_date,self.author.username)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-pub_date"]
```

Forms.py :

```
class CommentaireForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Commentaire
        fields = ['text']
```

Views.py :

```
class PostDetail(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = PostDisplay.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = PostComment.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

class PostDisplay(DetailView):
    model = Post

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDisplay, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['form'] = CommentaireForm()
        return context

class PostComment(SingleObjectMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'blogengine/post_detail.html'
    form_class = CommentaireForm
    model = Post

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        #    return HttpResponseForbidden()

        self.object = self.get_object()        
        form = self.get_form()

        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)


    def form_valid(self, form):
        """
        If the form is valid, redirect to the supplied URL
        """
        form.save(commit=False)
        form.post = self.object
        form.author = self.request.user
        form.pub_date = datetime.now()
        form.publish = True
        form.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

When Django save the form, i have this exception :

> NOT NULL constraint failed: blogengine_commentaire.pub_date

The values i set for the excluded fields (author, post, pub_date) in "form_valid" are not taken into account, they seem to stay NULL

Could you explain me why because i am lost ?

Thanks

Comment: *What* are you doing in PostDetail? What is the point of that class?

Comment: Hi, I try to follow the example of the Django Doc, to build a CBV to manage DetailView and From : https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.9/topics/class-based-views/mixins/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to rewrite `form_valid` method like that

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    """
    If the form is valid, redirect to the supplied URL
    """
    model_instance = form.save(commit=False)
    model_instance.post = self.object
    model_instance.author = self.request.user
    model_instance.pub_date = datetime.now()
    model_instance.publish = True
    model_instance.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Because `save(commit=False)` will return you an `Post` instance that you then need to populate and save.

Comment: @Nizaleto if you feel that it solves your problem you can accept the answer, so people will see that the problem is solved.

Comment: I am new in Django an maybe i start too fast with CBV and Mixins, and the offical doc is a little incomplete ... There is maybe a simpliest way to do, tanks again for sharing your knowledge